# Nested query in Redis

Tags: caching, redis

I am new to redis. I have to implement a mac address table cache using redis.
Each entry in the cache will have the following info

(1). Mac address - array of 6 bytes

(2). vlan - integer value

(3). Interface id - integer value (ok to be a string if needed instead).

The combination of Mac-address + Vlan is unique across the cache. So this is probably the key ?

I want to to be able to query my cache in multiple ways, for eg :

(1). Get me all the entries that have vlan == 20

(2). Get me all entries that have vlan == 20, interface-id == 5000

What would be the best way to store this in Redis. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Mo

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_hashes.htm

Comment: Are these the **only** query types?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only these two queries, keep the data in a single Sorted Set.

When [`ZADD`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd)ing a new MAC, use a score of 0 and construct your member (a string) in the following way:

```
ZADD MAC-address-table 0 <vlan>:<interface-id>:<MAC>
```

In the above, make sure that both the vlan and the interface-id are constant-width left-padded with 0s as needed. Assuming these are 32-bit unsigned ints, this would look like this:

```
ZADD MAC-address-table 0 00020:05000:XYZCBA
```

Using 0 as a the score will cause the Sorted Set to be sorted lexicographically, so you can use [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex). The 1st query is:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX MAC-address-table 00020: 00020:\xff
```

(`\xff` is character 255, and being the last character means it is the last in the lexical order). Similarly, the 2nd query:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX MAC-address-table 00020:05000 00020:05000\xff
```

Comment: Thanks all. Itamar : When we insert entries is there a way to tell redis to create a new entry only if the mac-address + vlan combination entry doesn't exist, otherwise just update the existing entry. Or should we do the check explicitly ?

Comment: To dedup you'll need to keep the MAC+vlan in another data structure - a regular Set seems appropriate - and manually check it before the ZADD

Comment: Hi Itamar, If I have to query for all the entries that have interface-id == 5000 how do I do that ?

Comment: That's exactly why I put my comment to your question above... you can't. Or rather, you'll either need to use an additional Sorted Set or a different technique called redimension - see the secondary indexes doc page at http://redis.io/topics/indexes

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly why I put my comment to your question above... you can't. Or rather, you'll either need to use an additional Sorted Set or a different technique called redimension - see the secondary indexes doc page at Redis.io

Comment: Oops - that was supposed to be a comment rather then an answer... Moving it there and deleting this, but you're most welcome :)